# How can I use the command vars()[x] into a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is a little longer than the following example, but anyways, it doesn't work and I have no idea how to figure out. I need to use the variables like strain1, strain2 to be assigned with arrays, but first of all, I'm trying to assign an empty list `[]`. If I don't use a function, that works. I need to use the block several times tho, that's why I need this function.

```
def test():
    for i in xrange(11):
         v = 'strain' + '%d' % i
         vars()[v] = []

test()
strain5

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    strain5
NameError: name 'strain5' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the [`globals()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) instead.

`vars()` (without arguments) returns the *current* namespace, in a function that is the local namespace, not the module globals.

Demo:

```
>>> def test():
...     for i in xrange(11):
...          v = 'strain' + '%d' % i
...          globals()[v] = []
... 
>>> test()
>>> strain5
[]
```

However, you want to rethink your variables. Invariably, you really want to create a list or dictionary instead:

```
strains = [[] for _ in xrange(11)]
```

creates 11 nested lists, which you access with `strains[0]`, `strains[1]`, etc.